# How do I match across line breaks with JavaScript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(?!.*www)(?!.*http)(?!.*@)(?!.*\.com)(?!.*\.pt)(?!.*co\.uk).+$/i.test(value);
        },
        "Description field can not include e-mail and/or urls."
    );
    $("#regForm").validate();
});
```

If I have a text like this, I get an error, because of the line break

```
A Loja virtual possui uma vasta linha de bijouterias folheadas a ouro e prata. São produtos bastante procurados e com preços muito acessíveis(50% de desconto no atacado).
Ha mais de 10 anos no mercado de folheados.

Produtos de excelente qualidade.
```

If I have this text, without line breaks, it works fine:

```
A Loja virtual possui uma vasta linha de bijouterias folheadas a ouro e prata. São produtos bastante procurados e com preços muito acessíveis(50% de desconto no atacado).Ha  mais de 10 anos no mercado de folheados.Produtos de excelente qualidade.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11):

`.` does not match linebreaks by default. Usually, the `s` (called `singleline` or `dotall`) modifier changes that. Unfortunately, it is not supported by JavaScript.

There is (a slightly verbose) trick to get around that. The character class `[\s\S]` matches any space and any non-space character. I.e. any character. So you would need to go with this:

```
/^(?![\s\S]*www)(?![\s\S]*http)(?![\s\S]*@)(?![\s\S]*\.com)(?![\s\S]*\.pt)(?![\s\S]*co\.uk)[\s\S]+$/i
```

Alternatively, (only in JavaScript) you can use the "candle operator" `[^]` which also matches any single character (since it's a negation of the empty character class, i.e. it matches any character not in the empty set). Whether you find that more or less readable is a matter of taste I guess:

```
/^(?![^]*www)(?![^]*http)(?![^]*@)(?![^]*\.com)(?![^]*\.pt)(?![^]*co\.uk)[^]+$/i
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner that is what I've search for an hour. `[\s\S]` Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MysterX actually, in the meantime I've found out that in JavaScript you can also use `[^]` (a character class that matches any character except the empty set, i.e. every set). The semantics might be a bit obscurer but once you know why it works I find it much more readable.

Comment: Yep, this even better readable and also works so I'll use it. Thanks again :-)