# RegEx, extract text between keys

Tags: javascript, regex

**Given:**

```
This is some text which could have 
line breaks and tabs before and after {code}
and I want them {code} to be replaced {code}in pairs{code} without any issues.
```

**I want:**

```
This is some text which could have 
line breaks and tabs before and after <code>
and I want them </code> to be replaced <code>in pairs</code> without any issues.
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egrwD/1

**Simple working text sample:**

```
var sample1 = 'test test test {code}foo bar{code} {code}good to know{code}';
var regEx1 = new RegExp('(\{code\})(.*?)(\{code\})', 'gi');
var r1 = sample1.replace(regEx1, '<code>$2</code>');
```

**Gives:**

```
test test test <code>foo bar</code> <code>good to know</code>
```

**Non working sample:**

```
var sample2 = 'test test test {code}\tfoo bar{code} {code}\r\ngood to know{code}';
var regEx2 = new RegExp('(\{code\})(.*?)(\{code\})', 'gi');
var r2 = sample2.replace(regEx2, '<code>$2</code>');
```

**Gives:**

```
test test test {code}   foo bar{code} {code}
good to know{code}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to [make the pattern match across line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13519970/139010), properly escape that first `{`, and use a regex literal to fix the need to double-escape backslashes in the string:

```
/(\{code\})([\s\S]*?)(\{code\})/gi
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/QNak5

Note that you don't even need the capturing parentheses around the `{code}`s:

```
/\{code\}([\s\S]*?)\{code\}/gi
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Jk5cr

Comment: @yckart and there's nothing in the OP to indicate that it needs to.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally correct! It was just a side-note ;) Here's my fix: `/\{\s*code\s*\}([\s\S]*?)\{\s*code\s*\}/gi`