# Regex to match string between asterisk with line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Example:

```
blah blah * Match this text Match this text
            Match this text
            Match this text
            Match this text
            *
more text more text
```

How to get string from inside the asterisk with the line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated match here. Notice that I escaped `\` the literal newline for this example.

```
var myString = "blah blah * Match this text Match this text\
            Match this text\
            Match this text\
            Match this text\
            *\
more text more text";

var result = myString.match(/\*([^*]*)\*/);
console.log(result[1]);

// => " Match this text Match this text            Match this text            Match this text            Match this text            "
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/82302)

If you don't want the leading or trailing whitespace, you can use the following to make it non greedy.

```
var result = myString.match(/\*\s*([^*]*?)\s*\*/);
console.log(result[1]);

// => "Match this text Match this text            Match this text            Match this text            Match this text"
```

Comment: This works although I don't want the asterisk in the final output.  Thanks.

Comment: The asterick won't be in the output if you refer to your capturing group.

Comment: Nevermind I see the output is in index one.  However, I am curious as to why my input returns 3 matches, with the last being a number?  See JsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gfF33/

Comment: You're using a `for in` loop to iterate over an array, which will also iterate over the properties. In this case, you're also accessing `index` property which represents the zero-based location of the match within the string. http://jsfiddle.net/gfF33/1/

Comment: Also, you call the variable `matches` in your code but it's worth bearing in mind that you're actually only finding a single match.

Answer (score 0):

`[\s\S]` matches any space and any non-space character. I.e. any character, even line breaks. (tested [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C*%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%5C*&input=blah%20blah%20*%20dsdfdfsdfds%20fddf%20ddfd%20fd%0Adfdsfdsd%20fdsfsd%20fds%20fds%20%0Asdf%20sd%20fd%20f%20df%20ds%20f*%20bafdfd%20dfsdf%0Adsfdsf%20df%20dsf%20ds%20)).

```
\*[\s\S]*\*
```

[Also, check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13519970/1290264).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/(\*)([^\0].+)*(\*)/g`:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gLhPr/)

```
var regex = /(\*)([^\0].+)*(\*)/g; 
var input = "* Match this text Match this text (this is a line break -> \n) Match this text (\n) Match this text Match this text * more text more text"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
    var matches = input.match(regex);
    for(var match in matches) {
        alert(matches[match]);
    } 
}
else {
    alert("No matches found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers will help you both [now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/1723135) and in the [future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247331/1723135).

From the console:

```
> "blah blah * Match this text Match this text\
            Match this text\
            Match this text\
            Match this text\
            *\
more text more text".match(/[*]([^*]*)[*]/)[1]   

" Match this text Match this text            Match this text            Match this text            Match this text            "
```